# Select all rows where related table has no records with value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables:

Person table

```
ID  NAME
1   Matt
2   Josh
```

Files table

```
FILE_ID     PERSON_ID   TYPE
1           1           Photo
2           2           Text
3           2           Text
```

I want to return all people that do NOT have any files with type of Photo existing in the other table.

In the above scenario I would like to return:

```
ID  NAME
2   Josh
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from person p
where not exists (select 1
                  from files f
                  where f.person_id = p.id and f.type = 'Photo'
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `files(person_id, type)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `not exists` :

```
select p.*
from person p
where not exists (select 1 from files f where f.person_id = p.id and f.type = 'photo');
```

Answer (score 2):

use `not in`

```
select p.*
from person p
where p.id not in (select id from Files f where f.type = 'photo');
```